# Responsive Email: Complete list of applicable CSS selectors and attributes

Tags: css, html, email, responsive-design

I'm curious, are there any good resources for checking compatibility across browsers, email clients, and mobile OSs? Can most any CSS selector be used for responsive email?

Comment: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to email blasts, I always approach the task like it's the late-90s. Practices, that you would typically steer clear of these days, have the best possibility of working across the most e-mail clients.

I'm talking tables, inline CSS, as rudimentary as you can make it.

With that said, the tool I use to test the output is http://litmus.com it will show you exactly what your HTML will look like on various email clients across various OSes and devices.

As others have already noted, http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ is a good resource to see what will work and won't.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a CSS file in email. Most email clients, like Gmail, will cut it off, and your content may look very strange without it.

If you want to use styles inside your email message, this is an easy way to compare different clients:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

@APAD1 said:

> When it comes to email blasts, I always approach the task like it's the late-90s. Practices, that you would typically steer clear of these days, have the best possibility of working across the most e-mail clients.

Sadly, yes.

A tool that helps you maintain sanity while you do that inline dance is [MailChimp's CSS Inliner](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/). Paste normal code in, get horrible code out.

You can also use something like PHP to create the email templates and then echo styles via variables.

```
$title = "color: white; font-weight: normal;";
$header = "background-color: blue;";

<td style="<? echo $header; ?>">
    <h2 style="<? echo $title; ?>"> My Header </h2>
</td>
```

This works particularly well if your app is sending automated messages to users because it still affords you the benefits of keeping all of your styles in one place. I created a CakePHP helper so I could reuse the styles across a number of different system email templates.

In the end, while kind of ugly and still a pain compared to normal HTML/CSS development, it's not that different from adding class names to elements. And really, inline styles is the only thing you can be somewhat confident will work cross email client.